# merge file in bash by pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

I am new to linux and I have a simple question.
**My task**
I have two files, A.txt and B.txt
A.txt
1
2
3
B.txt
4
5
6
I want to have a outcome as:
C.txt
1 4
2 5
3 6

**My question**
Basically I can use a script to do this, but I would like to see if I can do this in bash with pipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `paste` command:

```
paste -d' ' A.txt B.txt > C.txt
```

**Test:**

```
$ head *.txt
==> A.txt <==
1
2
3

==> B.txt <==
4
5
6

$ paste -d' ' A.txt  B.txt > C.txt
$ cat C.txt 
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: or do `cat A.txt | paste -d' ' - B.txt` with `pipes`.