# Bind two files by column in bash

Tags: bash, cbind

when i have two files such as file A

```
012
658
458
895
235
```

and file B

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

how could they be joined in bash? The output shoudl just be

```
1012
2658
3458
4895
5235
```

really I just want to bind by column such as in R (cbind).

Comment: possible duplicate of [merge file in bash by pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847534/merge-file-in-bash-by-pipe)

Answer (score 13):

Assuming columns are in equal length in both files, you can use `paste` command:

```
paste --delimiters='' fileB fileA
```

The default delimiter for paste command is TAB. So '' make sure no delimiter is in place.

Comment: if i would need them to be tab delimited I could just use paste --delimiters='\t' fileB fileA?

Comment: In that case, you can remove delimiter altogether: `paste fileB fileA` as `\t` is the default delimiter. For space delimited: `paste -d' ' fileB fileA `

Answer (score 2):

Like this maybe:

```
paste -d'\0' B A
```

Or, if you like `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[FNR]=$0;next} {print $0,A[FNR]}' OFS='' A B
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure Bash and no external commands:

```
while read -u 3 A && read -u 4 B; do
    echo "${B}${A}"
done 3< File_A.txt 4< File_B.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "run complete" *.err | awk -F: '{print $1}'|sort > a
ls ../bam/*bam | grep -v temp | awk -F[/_] '{print $3".err"}' | sort > b 
diff <(grep "run complete" *.err | awk -F: '{print $1}'|sort) <(ls ../bam/*bam | grep -v temp | awk -F[/_] '{print $3".err"}' )
paste a b
```